# What does Cons and :-: mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

In [LYAHFGG](http://learnyouahaskell.com/), one chapter says that list is defined as:

```
data List a = Cons a (List a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)
```

I understand what most of this means apart from Cons. When I try `:t Cons` and `:i Cons` in `ghci` I get a  not in scope error. Later on in the chapter it also talks about :-: and how it's the same as Cons

```
infixr 5 :-:  
data List a = Empty | a :-: (List a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)
```

But again I really don't understand what this `:-:` means either.

In another resource, in a section about data types, they define the following data type:

```
data Expr = X
      | Const Int
      | Expr :+: Expr
      | Expr :-: Expr
      | Expr :*: Expr
      | Expr :/: Expr
      | IfZero Expr Expr Expr
      deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

Where `IfZero p q r` is the same as `if p == 0 then q else r`. Is this the same thing? I'm mostly confused as to what the two `:`s mean, and if it's mandatory syntax or just style choice.

Comment: I suggest you read up on data declaration syntax.  Those are constructors.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson any resources you could suggest? Neither of these explain very well

Comment: I've always felt that wikibooks is an under-rated resource (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Type_declarations) but LYAH does have a chapter for this (http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#algebraic-data-types).

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson yes this is the chapter of LYAH I was talking about. Maybe I didn't articulate my problem very well. The book doesn't seem to explain exactly what :-: means. I can't see the function defined or mentioned anywhere else in the chapter.

Comment: That _is_ the definition.  It constructs a value of type `List a`.  `Empty` is a valid expression and represents an empty list.  `Cons 1 Empty` is a valid expression and its value is of type `List Int`.

Comment: The output of `:t Cons`, once you get your scope problem sorted out, will be `Cons ::  a -> List a -> List a`, and the output of `:i Cons` will be the line you're asking about in your question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> ```
> data List a = Cons a (List a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)
> ```
>
> I understand what most of this means apart from Cons. When I try `:t Cons` and `:i Cons` in `ghci` I get a  not in scope error.

You need to load the Haskell source file with the `data` declaration before you can have `Cons` in scope. Or, alternatively, you can enter that `data` line directly in GHCi.

For serious code, it's easier if you put it in a file and load it. This is because the learning process typically involves modifying the file a bit, reloading it, trying some test in GHCi, modifying the file again, etc. Doing this in GHCi is cumbersome.

Anyway, `Cons` is just the constructor name -- it is an arbitrary name. You can use `data List a = Foobar a (List a) ....` and name it `Foobar`, if you wish. `Cons` is a historic name, though, originating from Lisp.

`:-:` is another arbitrary name for the constructor, except that it can be used *infix*. I.e. instead of `Cons 1 someList` one can write `1 :-: someList`.

Comment: Ah thank you I was starting to suspect that was it while playing around with it. I think too much coffee and too little sleep is a bad idea.

Answer (score 8):

`:-:` is just an infix name for a data constructor. You could see that `data` declaration as equivalent to

```
data List a = Empty | (:-:) a (List a)
```

Semantically, there is no difference between using `(:-:)` or `Cons`, but it's much nicer to read

```
1 :-: 2 :-: 3 :-: 4 :-: Empty
```

than either

```
Cons 1 (Cons 2 (Cons 3 (Cons 4 Empty)))
```

or

```
1 `Cons` (2 `Cons` (3 `Cons` (4 `Cons` Empty)))
```

Comment: You can use `Cons` in infix position as well, as long as it is enclosed in backquotes. Any constructor name beginning with `:` (such as `:` or `:-:`) is special-cased as an infix constructor and is used as such without enclosing it in backquotes.

Comment: @chepner Sure, but then the backticks themselves are annoying.

Comment: I can't find `:-:` in hoogle, and ghci doesn't seem to recognise it. How does it differ from `:`?

Comment: @ZoeyHewll `:-:` isn't in the standard library. You have to define it first.